# how can show block create information. when i make a contract creation

Tags: sendrawtransaction, sendtransaction

How can show below information at windows command console? When i use web3 to make contract creation. i browse some website. Some website tell me to use sendRawTransaction. But the sendRawTransaction is no in web3.js version 1.3.3. Can you tell me to display below information?

Transaction: 0x62c146c42c17ec030b5dc9befa5058dd4b3e86765a92ed1cd3f6436872a1a76a
Contract created: 0xb11a375fc9ffc6681f5ac1efb06e2f64dc7711e7
Gas usage: 99213
Block Number: 11  Block Time: Fri Feb 05 2021 11:15:48 GMT+0800 (CST)

Thank you very much.

Comment: after contract has been crated, all its info is in the Receipt. you have to get the receipt using transaction hash

Comment: do you mean i change to getTransactionReceipt? So, i can get receipt.